# Can we disable a microphone from a c++ code

Tags: c++, windows, microphone

I want to "disable" a microphone(an audio capturing device) from my c++ program.
if we can do it in windows GUI then there might be a way to do it via c++ code.
We can mute the microphone but the requirement is disabling it. I googled a lot but couldn't find a way. 
Thank you.

Comment: whats the difference between muting and disabling a microphone?

Comment: mute is just volume 0 and disabled is a state.  Like it can't be used by any app.

Comment: you can try disabling a device by right clicking it and choosing disable :p

Comment: And if _you_ can disable it, who's to know another app won't re-enable it?

Comment: that's not a problem..just wanted to know if there is a way we can do it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

got answer to my question [here](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windowsdesktop/en-US/86936bae-093a-4559-9cf3-d237c7a457c2/how-to-enable-the-speaker-from-a-cc-program?forum=windowspro-audiodevelopment&prof=required)
A change is required in registry in value of HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\MMDevices\Audio\Render\'_some_id_'\ ***DeviceState***